# How to change the way my website appears on Google Search?

Tags: google-search

When I enter my homepage URL on Google, it shows "Index of ~/user" instead of my page title, i.e, "User|Home".

Is there a way to change the way my website appears on Google search? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

Your website page should have following tags for better SEO ranks and Search Engine Crawl.

Search engine will read the following data's from your web pages.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /> // You can specify the page need to index on Google and follow or not
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2" />
<meta name="description" content=" description." />
<title>My Page title</title>
```

Only setting above details will not improve your website appearance on Search engines.
Should have valid page content, and proper SEO friendly urls.

Hope it make sense..

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en) should explain everything.

Excerpt:

> As explained above, make sure every page on your site has a title
>   specified in the  tag. If you’ve got a large site and are
>   concerned you may have forgotten a title somewhere, the HTML
>   suggestions page in Webmaster Tools lists missing or potentially
>   problematic  tags on your site.